# Redirect the TCP traffic to stdin of CLI application?

Tags: windows, tcp, batch-file, command-line-interface

I have a console application, listening the `stdin` for the input data and printing the output to `stdout`. Is it possible to redirect the TCP traffic from the remote client to `stdin` of the launched application? Is it possible with Windows 7 toolchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) for Windows to listen for tcp connections and pipe the data stream to stdin and/or stdout.